# Best way to convert AVRational number to Double in C++

Tags: c++, double

I want to convert an AVRational number that FFmpeg uses for light metadata in movies so I can use it with Nvidia API.

Those values are from FFmpeg mastering_display_metadata.h
"Max luminance of mastering display (cd/m^2)."

Value is in cd/m².

This goes to Nvidia API that expects:
"Maximum display mastering luminance ([0x0001-0xFFFF] = [1.0 - 65535.0] cd/m^2)"

I can convert like this:

```
HDR10MetaData.MaxMasteringLuminance = static_cast<uint32_t>(av_q2d(displayMetadata.max_luminance) * 10000.0f);
```

Or like this:

```
hdr10.MaxMasteringLuminance = av_q2d (picture.displayMetadata.max_luminance);
```

Which is is correct that outputs what Nvidia drivers are expecting?

Comment: Rather use a [`std::ratio`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/ratio/ratio), `double` values aren't accurate.`

Comment: What do you mean? Can you post an example?